# Rake trouble finding MySQL after uninstalling Rails 3.0.0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

So I thought I had fixed the problem  posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654921/trouble-with-ruby-on-rails-with-rake) and I uninstalled Rails 3.0.0 with `sudo gem uninstall rails -v 3.0.0`, but then I had troubles with other things. I took rogerdpack's advice to a different level and uninstalled all of my ruby gems and mysql, then reinstalled them. Now I get the following:

```
Icarus:temporary atg$ rails shopping -d mysql
      create  ........
Icarus:temporary atg$ cd shopping/
Icarus:shopping atg$ rake db:create
(in /Users/atg/temporary/shopping)
Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"shopping_development", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe reinstall rails?

Comment: So run `sudo gem uninstall rails; sudo gem install rails -v 2.3.8` is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted after the install and everything worked again. So the key fix was to uninstall and reinstall everything, and then to restart so that changes can take effect.